# Determine left/right based on headings of in & out legs

Tags: pgrouting, routing, navigation, open-source-routing-machine

I'm analyzing roads layer to create navigation layer. Each vector Linestring segment has direction of traffic.

Turn defined as where 2 directional segments meet.

However, I find it challenging to associate with turns what we know as "left/right" turn association.

Playing with headings (In both notations: [0,360], [-180,180]) - it's hard to find a formula. Example for the [0,360] notation:

[image]

However, I assume there is a known solution for that, since it's so common task (although I didn't find related questions here).